# WPF CheckBox's IsChecked property doesn't match binding source's value

Tags: wpf, binding, checkbox, ischecked

In my WPF application I have a [`CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.aspx) whose [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) value is bound to a property in my viewmodel. Notice that I have commented out the actual line which sets the value in my viewmodel. It's the standard pattern:

#### View.xaml

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />
```

#### ViewModel.cs

```
public bool SomeProperty
{
    get { return this.mSomeProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.mSomeProperty)
        {
            //this.mSomeProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeProperty"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the `CheckBox` I expect nothing to happen, since the value of `this.mSomeProperty` does not get set. However the observed behavior is that the `CheckBox` is being checked and unchecked regardless of the value of `this.mSomeProperty`.

What is going on? Why isn't my binding forcing the `CheckBox` to show what the underlying data model is set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WPF does not automatically reload from the binding source after updating the source.  This is probably partly for performance reasons, but mostly to handle binding failures.  For example, consider a TextBox bound to an integer property.  Suppose the user types 123A.  WPF wants to continue showing what the user typed so that they can correct it, rather than suddenly resetting the TextBox contents to the old value of the property.

So when you click the CheckBox, WPF assumes that it should continue to display the *control* state, not to re-check the bound property.

The only way I've found around this, which is not very elegant, is to raise PropertyChanged *after* WPF has returned from calling the property setter.  This can be done using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```
set
{
  // ...actual real setter logic...
  Action notify = () => NotifyPropertyChanged(...);
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, notify);
}
```

This could be made a bit less horrible by consolidating it into the NotifyPropertyChanged implementation so that you wouldn't have to pollute individual properties with this implementation concern.  You might also be able to use NotifyOnSourceUpdated and the SourceUpdated attached event, but I haven't explored this possibility.

Comment: A creative solution certainly, but... ugh... I hope there's a cleaner solution out there!

Comment: Microsoft changed binding behavior in .NET 4.0 so that controls will now check the bound property after setting it. http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/

Comment: Great answer from itowlson and good feedback by emddudley.  I can confirm that this behavior only happens in .NET 3.5 - it seems to have been fixed in WPF in .NET 4.